# Inductive limit of Frechet spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

The inductive limit of a countable number of Frechet spaces is an LF-space.  What is the inductive limit when we allow the family of Frechet spaces to be labeled by a directed index set instead of the natural numbers?

Comment: How is the proof going for the case of natural numbers?

Comment: If you're not adding restrictions, all you can say is that it's an [ultra-bornological space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ultra-bornological_space).

Comment: In fact, if we allow uncountable directed colimits, we also must restrict ourselves to stay in the category of locally convex spaces, or else these colimits need not exist. For example, and uncountable coproduct of one-dimensional spaces does not exist in the larger category. :)

Comment: What is an LP-space? Dieudonne-Schwartz (in the strict case) and Grothendieck used *LF-space*. There is a theorem of Valdivia that every ultrabornological locally convex space is a (non-countable) inductive limit of Hilbert spaces even with nuclear linking maps.

Comment: @Jochen thanks that was a typo, I meant LF-space.

Comment: A simplified version of the case that I am interested in is the following: consider $A^r$ = set of real-valued functions $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ which are $C^\infty$ on the interior $(0,\infty)$, and such that $|f(x)- a_r(x)x^r| =O(x^r)$, for some smooth function $a_r(x)$ and $r \in R$. Then on each $A^r$ we have the family of seminorms given by $|f|_{r,m,K} = \inf \{c\} + \| f \|_{m,n}$

Comment: where  $ \| f \|_{m,n}$ is the sup of the first $m$ derivatives over the compact $[1/n,n]$, and the infimum is taken over the best constants that define the above $O(x^r)$ behaviour on the compact set $[0,1/n]$.
Then I believe that each $A^r$ is a Frechet space and I want to see what is understand the topology of $A= \cup A^r$.

Comment: @paulgarrett I guess there is no problem here as a Frechet space is locally convex (and complete wrt a translational invariant metric). BTW thanks for posting your lecture notes, I had only read some of the functional analysis ones and they are very good.

Comment: @inquisitor, you're very welcome. But about that uncountable coproduct: in the larger category, even if the "limitands" are locally convex, there need not exist a coproduct in the larger category. E.g., the locally convex coproduct (which does exist) is not a coproduct in the larger category. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett I'm afraid I don't understand what do you mean by 'larger category'

Comment: @inquisitor, there is a category of locally convex TVS's, and then there is the larger category of not-necessarily-locally-convex TVS's.